# Updating field based on sorting of another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a user table which contains among others money, level and ranking.

```
Id | money| ranking| level
---------------------------
1  |30000|    1         1
2  |20000|    2         3
3  |10000|    3         2
4  |50000|    4         2
```

I want to update the ranking field based on user level (first filter) and money.

That is a user in higher level will always be ranked higher.

That is i want the table after the update like this:

```
Id | money| ranking| level
---------------------------
1  |30000|    4         1
2  |20000|    1         3
3  |10000|    3         2
4  |50000|    2         2
```

Thanks!

Comment: What if two users are tied with equal money and level? Also you need to store or just `select` this?

Comment: @MartinSmith, OP does say `update the field`

Comment: @paqogomez but do they *really* need this? How do they plan on keeping it in synch with changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a side note, I would NOT store this field within the database - storing values that are dependent on other records in the table make maintenance much more difficult.

Here's a query that would work as a view or within a stored procedure:

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    [money],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by [level] desc, [money] desc) AS [ranking],
    [level]
FROM myTable
```

If you REALLY wanted to update the table just make the query a subquery to an update:

```
UPDATE m1
    SET ranking = m2.ranking
FROM myTable m1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        ID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by [level] desc, [money] desc) ranking
     FROM myTable) m2
    ON m1.ID = m2.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to select then here is the query :

```
select *, dense_rank() over (order by level desc, mony desc) as newranking from YourTable
```

and if you want to update then :

```
;with cte_toupdate (ranking, newranking)
as (
select ranking, dense_rank() over (order by level desc, mony desc) as newranking from YourTable
)

Update cte_toupdate set ranking = newranking

select * from YourTable
```

check here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8d6d3/10

Note : if you want unique ranks then use Row_Number() instead of dense_rank().

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #tt
  (
     id      INT,
     mony    INT,
     ranking INT,
     levell  INT
  )

INSERT INTO #tt
VALUES      (1,30000,1,1),
            (2,20000,2,3),
            (3,10000,3,2),
            (4,50000,4,2)

UPDATE a
SET    ranking = rnk
FROM   #tt a
       JOIN (SELECT Row_number()
                      OVER (
                        ORDER BY levell DESC, mony DESC) AS rnk,
                    *
             FROM   #tt) b
         ON a.levell = b.levell
            AND a.mony = b.mony
```